# How to access values from kotlin MutableMap<String, Value>?

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap, gradle-kotlin-dsl, mutablemap

I am using Kotlin to access the response from a DialogFlow agent. The response in android console is as follows,

```
parameters {
  fields {
    key: "EmployeeID"
    value {
      number_value: 12345.0
    }
  }
}
```

In kotlin, I am using SessionClient to create a function that returns a custom response of multiple fields,

```
fun detectIntentTexts(
  text: String,
  sessionId: String,
  languageCode: String
): TextResponse {
  val sessionsSettings = SessionsSettings.newBuilder()
    .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
    .build()
  SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings).use {
    sessionsClient - >
      val session = SessionName.of(credentials.projectId, sessionId)
    val textInput = TextInput.newBuilder()
      .setText(text).setLanguageCode(languageCode)
    val queryInput = QueryInput
      .newBuilder().setText(textInput).build()
    val response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput)

    return TextResponse(response.queryResult.fulfillmentText, response.queryResult.parameters.fieldsMap)
  }
}
```

In an another Kotlin class, I am trying to access `response.queryResult.parameters.fieldsMap` using getValue(key:String) as the fieldsMap returns it of type MutableMap<String, Value>.

Whenever I try to access the value of the key,

```
 Log.i("TEST",answer.parametersMap.getValue("EmployeeID").toString())
```

It keeps throwing the following error on build,

```
Cannot access class 'com.google.protobuf.Value'. 
Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

> **Note:** When I access the `response.queryResult.parameters.fieldsMap.values.toString()` it does not throw any error. I have also tried adding protobuf dependencies in build.gradle file using this [documentation](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/100#issuecomment-334912976), it still gives the above error on build.

It would be great if someone could resolve it in kotlin and provide some insight as to why its not accessible.